# TypeScript union of type is resolved as intersection of types

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0, union-types

I have this snippet

```
class J {
  constructor(public foo: number) {}
}

class B {
 constructor(public bar: string) {}
}

interface Cache {
 json?: J;
 binary?: B;
}

function test(key: "json" | "binary", data: J | B, obj: Cache) {
  obj[key] = data;
}
```

If you try this code in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/, the line `obj[key] = data;` is having the following error

> Type 'J | B' is not assignable to type 'J & B'.
>     Type 'J' is not assignable to type 'J & B'.
>       Property 'bar' is missing in type 'J' but required in type 'B'.

There's obviously something I am missing but I can't figure out what. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript can't tell which property of `Cache` you are trying to update, and when in doubt he considers that the value you are trying to insert should be able to fit both. Which the `J | B can't.`

You could change your `test` function signature slightly to use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt)

```js
function test(update: Partial<Cache>, obj: Cache) {
    Object.assign(obj, update);
}
```

That way Typescript can be sure that the key/value pairs you are passing it are valid for the `Cache` class.

Comment: @rocketer `Partial` is a much better choice here IMO. I would go with this if you don't have other constraints.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I agree, I also don't want to use generics in that case

Answer (score 4):

There is no relation between `key` and `data`, so you could call test with `test( "json", new B())` and the assignment would not be valid.

If you use a generic type parameter (lets call it `K`) for the key and type `data` as `Cache[K]`, typescript will allow the assignment. (Even though it is still not 100% type safe as `K` could be a union and the same issue as described above could happen):

```
class J {
  constructor(public foo: number) {}
}

class B {
 constructor(public bar: string) {}
}

interface Cache {
 json?: J;
 binary?: B;
}

function test<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K, data: Cache[K], obj: Cache) {
  obj[key] = data;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBS0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQAOBARiAJbDQBm66AXNJgQLbUCmeAJSIAvkjFJQkGACFEKDNnxES5KrQbRqYPB1x46mAObCEYiYZwCmYYH2gBhWwAt7yaACsIWAPwdYANwo1IY6AJ5+0DJBEkwEmMR0WNBWuAA8ANLQfAAeVpgAJjAA1nxh6EyOLnwAfGSlYRwZADTQBWA4YBxOwK4A2hkAuq3o1B7d1aYo0KMefQ2D0AC8bR1gMUA)