# Why is this type union resolved as an intersection, in typescript?

Tags: typescript

**I'm having trouble understanding the mechanism behind a typescript error I'm getting** - I'm convinced there's something basic doing a "whoosh" sound as it flies over my head.

I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389826/typescript-union-of-type-is-resolved-as-intersection-of-types) question on the topic, but while the error looks the same, the setup seems quite different to me.

This is the definition I'm referencing, cut for brevity.

```
type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
  // ...
  data:
    | (number | null)[]
    | {
        x: any;
        y: any;
        // ...
      }[]
    | [number, number | null][]
    | [number, (number | null)[]][];
}[]
```

And this is the bad function, which takes an `{x:number, y:number}` array.

```
function composeSeries(input: { x: number; y: number }[]) {
  const series: ApexAxisChartSeries = [
    { name: "A", data: [] },
    { name: "B", data: [] },
  ];

  input.forEach((datum) => {
    series[0].data.push(datum); // <-- This line right here gives the error.
  });

  return series;
}
```

Now, what's confusing me is that given the type definition, I would expect a `{x:number, y:number}` object to be a perfectly valid element of `data`, but typescript is complaining that

> Argument of type `'{ x: number; y: number; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `number & { x: any; y: any; fillColor?: string | undefined; strokeColor?: string | undefined; meta?: any; goals?: any; } & [number, number | null] & [number, (number | null)[]]'`.
>
> Type `'{ x: number; y: number; }'` is not assignable to type `'number'`.

And I'm here like, **where in the bleep bloop are those intersections in the error coming from**, if the type definition uses unions?

As additional context:

1. It's not only the object that gives an error. If I use `[x,y]` tuples or just a number array, the compiler still perks up
2. I'm using TS 4.5.4
3. I'm quite positive the issue exists in this code: the TS playground gives the same error

For reference, this is the full type definition:

```
type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
  name?: string
  type?: string
  color?: string
  data:
    | (number | null)[]
    | {
        x: any;
        y: any;
        fillColor?: string;
        strokeColor?: string;
        meta?: any;
        goals?: any;
      }[]
    | [number, number | null][]
    | [number, (number | null)[]][];
}[]
```

Any clarification is deeply appreciated!

**Edit**: an example of the error can be found on the TS playground [here](https://tsplay.dev/wX76LW), courtesy of @jcalz

Comment: Where did you get your type information from? It could be the added type information is not 100% correct or is "difficult" to get right if someone had to interpret the possible options.

Comment: It's always good to give a [mre] suitable for pasting into an IDE without unrelated issues so people can play around with it and see what's happening without being distracted (e.g., if "the condition itself isn't relevant" then having an error on an undeclared `condition` variable that the developer has to spend time looking at and consciously ignoring.  Instead you could just write `const index = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1` or even just `const index = 0` for all it matters).

Comment: In the interest of producing a [mre], does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX76LW) capture the problem you're having?  You have a union of array types and you're trying to push something onto it, and the compiler is introducing an intersection where you weren't expecting it?  (And if so, does https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types explain it for you?)

Comment: @crashmstr in this case the library itself (ApexCharts) includes types

Comment: @ChristianFratta Since they don't write it in TypeScript, there may be issues with how they do declare the types. Before I realized this was types for a library, I wrote up an answer on how *I* would fix it (someone else has written a similar one now too). You can either work around their types or do some hard casting. I'd suggest finding their support, because if that is the type declaration they use, it definitely has problems with TypeScript as-is.

Comment: @jcalz noted! I've now edited the question to include both of your suggestions (your playground example matches the issue, so I've included it directly). Many thanks!

Comment: @crashmstr I shall organize a date with TS generics, and then write the library authors about it once I can fully explain what's going on and the reasoning for the fix :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `(T | U)[]` and `T[] | U[]`.  In the first, each array element can be of type *T* or *U*.  In the second (which corresponds with your case) the array can only have elements of one of either type.

The question you have to ask yourself is this:  How can TypeScript know what elements are allowed when it doesn't know which type of an array a variable is?

```
const myArray: string[] | number[] = [];
myArray.push(5); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Take the example above.  TypeScript will throw an error no matter because whatever you push to that array will not comply with one of the possible types.

The good thing is that the TypeScript compiler is clever has heck and figured out in your case that a type can be derived that will comply with every possible condition.  This type happens to be the intersection of all possible element types, which is the most basic type that would meet the requirements.

Your options are either make the array allow any of the possible types, or make the series a generic that extends any one of the types.

**Option A: Array element can be one of many types**

```
type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
  name: string,
  data:
    (number 
      | null 
      | { x: any; y: any; } 
      | [number, number | null]
      | [number, (number | null)[]]
    )[]
};
```

**Option B: Generic type parameter can be one of many types**

```
type ChartDataType = (number | null)
  | { x: any; y: any; } 
  | [number, number | null] 
  | [number, (number | null)[]];

type ApexAxisChartSeries<T extends ChartDataType> = {
  name: string,
  data: T[]
}[];

function composeSeries<T extends ChartDataType>(input: T[]) {
  const series: ApexAxisChartSeries<T> = [
    { name: "A", data: [] },
    { name: "B", data: [] },
  ];

  input.forEach((datum) => {
    const index = (true) ? 0 : 1;
    series[index].data.push(datum);
  });

  return series;
}

composeSeries([{ x:1, y: 1}]); // returns { name, data: { x, y }[] }[]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the reason why a union type would be resolved as an intersection instead. Thank you for the clear explanation, seems like there's some generics investigation in my near future!